# Atom - Python Module Not Working "Module Not Found"

Tags: python, import, atom-editor

i wanted to install a python module in my atom project, but when i do
import package
it doesnt work, even tho i have installed it in my computer via pip install package.
What does work, is pip install package -t project_path,
but this does make my project messy af.
How can i fix that?

Comment: how many python version are installed? if 2 then check you installed on respective pip

Comment: i think i have 3 or so haha, how can i uninstall the ones i dont need?
I think i have 2.7, 3.5 and 3.8, my %Path% is 3.8, but python -V results in Python 3.5.0...